# Objective-c - Border is over other view

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to put a UILabel over my custom button. The problem is: when I add this label, it is under my button border, I want it over the border.

This is the image of my problem:

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [abril.com](http://m.abril.com/testing.png))</sub>
.

and this is the code:

```
        //#define DEFAULTCOLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:161.f/255.f blue:54.f/255.f alpha:1]

        UIButton *banner = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        banner.frame = CGRectMake(45, 45, 230, 190);
        [[banner layer] setBorderWidth:3.0f];
        [[banner layer] setBorderColor:DEFAULTCOLOR.CGColor];
        [self.view addSubview:banner];

        UILabel *overButtonLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 168, 20)];
        overButtonLabel.backgroundColor = DEFAULTCOLOR;
        overButtonLabel.text = @"Testing";

        float widthIs = [overButtonLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:overButtonLabel.frame.size
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:overButtonLabel.font }
                                                           context:nil].size.width;

        overButtonLabel.frame =CGRectMake(-10, -10, widthIs, 20);
        overButtonLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:15];
        overButtonLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [banner addSubview:overButtonLabel];
        [banner bringSubviewToFront:overButtonLabel];
```

Regards!

Comment: try 

      [self.view addSubview:overButtonLabel];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that as per CALayer class reference border are always draw above contents:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/borderWidth

You can do one thing take a view and add both button and label in that view.
In that view your label must be on the front.